# Receiving error while loading multiple files with GDAL

Tags: python, gis, raster, gdal, geotiff

I have read the path of the files using the following code.

```
import os
directory = os.listdir("/home/user/Downloads/SE_75_Ice")
fcount = len(directory)
i =0
while i < fcount :
    directory[i] = ('"'+'/home/user/Downloads/SE_75_Ice/'+directory[i]+'"')
    print(directory[i])
    i = i+1
```

And I tried to read several files using the code below.

```
from osgeo import gdal
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
while i < n: 
    directory[i] = ('"'+'path'+directory[i]+'"')
    ds = gdal.Open(directory[i], gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
    rb = ds.GetRasterBand(i)
    img_array_wake_1 = rb.ReadAsArray()
    plt.imshow(img_array_wake_1)
    plt.savefig('path/si%d.jpg'%i)
    i = i+1
```

When I run the above code, I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'

I think it may be directory list isn't string type so it can't be read path

Please let me know the solution to the above problem or how you can read multiple files at once.

Comment: Based on the error I would say the file you're reading is not a raster, or more probably the path is wrong. Can you give an example of your paths and files?

Comment: Val makes a good point.  In addition, to know what you should expect, run the following command on the file in question to get how many raster bands, geo info, and other attributes.  `gdalinfo <pathname>`.  Since you are using GDAL Libraries, you should have the command-line utilities installed as well.

Comment: i can't upload file. all files are over 1gb. and And I have confirmed that these files are RSATER files.
I also installed packages and tools with CONDA INSTALL.

Comment: There's no need to upload a file. Just share what `directory[i] = ('"'+'path'+directory[i]+'"')` or ` directory[i] = ('"'+'/home/user/Downloads/SE_75_Ice/'+directory[i]+'"')` gives you for a single iteration. Without knowing, I would say you have to remove the double quotes. GDAL reads paths like `"/home/user/datadirectory/raster.tif"`, notice it only has one pair of double quotes, making it a string in `python`